# C++ member function pointer use-case?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have been writing a small framework on OpenGL API using C++ with 2 classes :

- GameObject (Component Architecture):

  - Add MeshRenderer as Component.
  - Add Material as Component.
- Material:

  - Handles all the Shader Data, and attaches as a component to the GameObject.
  - Contains private: void RegisterComponent(RCUpdateCallback& funcPtr);
- MeshRenderer:

  - Handles the assigned mesh data (VAO, VBO, EBO etc)

    ```
    // routine to handle shader change  
    Contains private: void MeshRenderer::UpdateMaterial();
    ```

Now during runtime, if the user wants to change the Shader of the material, then the mesh class needs to be updated as well with the new data. So what I am trying is to store callback of `MeshRenderer::UpdateMaterial(SG_EUpdate& flag)` -> function inside the material class.

Here is the pseudocode for it:

```
/* Register the callback here for this mesh's Update method inside the constructor of the mesh*/
SGMeshRenderer::SGMeshRenderer( SGMeshFilter mesh_copy, SG_PTRS<SGMaterial> mat )
{
    SGUUIDGenerator::instance().Create( uuid );
    material = mat;
    material->RegisterComponent( this, &SGRenderer::UpdateMaterial );
}

/* Register Function inside the mesh class for storing all the callback */
void SGMaterial::RegisterComponent( SGRenderer* const object, RCUpdateMethod method )
{
    map_renderCompCallbacks.insert( MapRCUCallbacks::value_type( object, method ) );
}

/*   Whenever New Shader is set, material calls all the meshes UpdateMethod */
void SGMaterial::SetShader( SG_PTRS<Shader> const shader )
{
    activeShader = shader;
    std::cout << "START OF FUNCTION : " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Material name : " << name << " id : " << uuid << "Active Shader : " << activeShader->shaderProgramName << std::endl;
    std::cout << "END OF FUNCTION : " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    // Generate Shader data
    SGMaterialManager::instance().Create( uuid, *activeShader );
    // Update all the RendererComponents using this material ( ReBuild- VAOs)
    for( auto it = map_renderCompCallbacks.begin(); it != map_renderCompCallbacks.end(); it++ )
    {
        // using Object reference to call the stored pointer.
        // If we have the object reference we can do it->first->UpdateMethod() directly.
        ( it->first->*it->second )( SG_EUpdateFlag::MaterialUpdate );
    }
}
```

The problem is I can store the method as a callback, but when calling the method from the Material class, I also need the reference of the mesh object to call the respective function pointer.

Something like this: `MeshRenderer::*StoredFuncPointer(args);`

Now I do not see any point in storing the callbacks, if we are to send the object reference, I can just call all the method via reference.

So what is the point of having member pointers, if we need the object reference?

Comment: Calling a specific method of an object via pointer cannot be performed with a function pointer. A member function pointer is necessary as it involves the provided object pointer as well. (Without object pointer, you cannot call a non-static method, neither with member function pointer nor in any other way.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit @genpfault .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of having a pointer-to-member is that you can use it with any object, not just a predetermined one.

A pointer-to-member is more similar to an array index than a pointer; if you store the number `k`, you can retrieve the `k`:th element of any array, as long as you also know which array to retrieve it from.

If you want to call a function on a predetermined object, then pointer-to-member is not the thing you want - you probably want a `std::function` and `std::bind`.

A very simple example:

```
struct A
{
    A(const std::string& nm) : name(nm){}
    void f() { cout << name << " f\n";}
    void g() { cout << name << " g\n";}
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    A a("a");
    A b("b");
    using fun = std::function<void()>;
    std::vector<fun> fns = {std::bind(&A::f, a),
                            std::bind(&A::g, a),
                            std::bind(&A::f, b)};

    for (auto& f: fns)
        f();
}
```

Comment: I think std::function is what I am looking for, causing I want to call the member function of Class A, inside Class B without sending Class A object reference to Class B.
It would be helpful if you can  give a simple use case example.
Thanks.

Comment: what will that auto type deduce to?

Comment: @Tesla The type of the vector's elements, as usual. That is, `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try this in the code and get back.

Comment: Yup it is working, nice. Now i can map<uuid,UpdateMethod> instead of <object,UpdateMethod>. 
Thank you Sir.